# 『Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet』の『::』 はどういう意味でしょうか

Tags: aws, aws-cloudformation, yaml

## 疑問点

`Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet` の `::` の意味がわかりません。

## 疑問内容

例えば `Key: name` ならkeyの値がnameということを示しているかと思います。

ですが `Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet` は `:` が2つで、上記とは違った意味合いになるのかどうか調べたのですが明確な答えを見つけることができませんでした。

## 考えたこと

推測ですが、ネストを表現しているのかなと思いました。
（TypeがAWSのEC2のRouteTableだということ）

ただYAMLのネストは、例えば以下のように表現するので違うのかなとも思いました。

```
AvailabilityZone: !Select 
- 0- !GetAZs 
Ref: 'AWS::Region'
```

## お願いしたいこと

考え方が間違っていないかご指摘いただけますと幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

特に深い意味は無いかと思います。

> 推測ですが、ネストを表現しているのかなと思いました。

このような理解で良いかと思います。単に文字列と文字列を区切るために、珍しい文字にすることで、他の構文と区別しやすくして、テキスト処理しやすくしているだけと思います。

Comment: シンプルに考えるのが良いのですね！ありがとうございます！